# MS SQL value change

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL query that looks like this.

```
Select Timestamp, Value From [dbo].[nro_ReadRawDataByTimeFunction](
  'SV/SVTP01.BONF0335-D1-W1-BL1',
  '2017-11-01 00:00',
  '2017-12-01 00:00')
GO
```

This will return

```
    Timestamp        | Value
1   2017-11-01 10:00 | 0
2   2017-11-01 11:00 | 0
3   2017-11-01 12:00 | 0
4   2017-11-01 13:00 | 1
5   2017-11-01 14:00 | 1
6   2017-11-01 15:00 | 0
7   2017-11-01 16:00 | 0
8   2017-11-01 17:00 | 0
9   2017-11-01 18:00 | 1
10  2017-11-01 19:00 | 0
```

The full list is alot larger, and I'm only interested in in results where value change from last result, so in this case row 1,4,6,9,10

I know how to do it if it's directly from a table but not when it's from a function

Comment: why don't you  do it inside the function ?

Comment: Can't modify it since it's being used my multiple system that would break

Comment: @T.Nesset  did you find anything useful? Please accept the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i ended with is as following

```
@DECLARE @startDate DATE,
@tagName nVarChar(200);

WITH CTE AS( 
        SELECT Timestamp As StopTime, Value As [OFF], LAG(Value,1) OVER (order by Timestamp) As [ON], Quality
        FROM [dbo].[nrp_ReadRawDataByTimeFunction] (@TagName,@startDate, DATEADD(MONTH,2,@startDate)) 
        Where Quality & 127 = 100
),
CalenderCTE AS(
        SELECT [DATE] = DATEADD(Day,Number,@startDate)
        FROM master..spt_values
        WHERE Type='P'
        AND DATEADD(day,Number,@startDate) < DATEADD(MONTH,1,@startDate)
)

SELECT * FROM CTE
FULL OUTER JOIN 
CalenderCTE on CalenderCTE.Date = CAST(CTE.StopTime as [Date])
Where CTE.[OFF] != CTE.[ON}
```

This is just a tiny part of the query since it doing alot more which ain't included in the original post.

Thanks all for your input's, it help me on the way to the final result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this construction:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    Select  [Timestamp],
            [Value]
    From [dbo].[nro_ReadRawDataByTimeFunction](
      'SV/SVTP01.BONF0335-D1-W1-BL1',
      '2017-11-01 00:00',
      '2017-12-01 00:00')
)

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES c.*
FROM cte c
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM cte
    WHERE [Value] != c.[Value] AND c.[Timestamp] < [Timestamp]
    ORDER BY [Timestamp] ASC
) t
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.[Timestamp] ORDER BY c.[Timestamp] ASC)
```

Output:

```
Timestamp           Value
2017-11-01 19:00    0
2017-11-01 10:00    0
2017-11-01 13:00    1
2017-11-01 15:00    0
2017-11-01 18:00    1
```

**Explanation:**

```
SELECT *
FROM cte c
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM cte
    WHERE [Value] != c.[Value] AND c.[Timestamp] < [Timestamp]
    ORDER BY [Timestamp] ASC
) t
```

Here we select data from main table and with the help of OUTER APPLY add to each row data with different value and greater timestamp.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.[Timestamp] ORDER BY c.[Timestamp] ASC)
```

Hope, you are familiar with [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) it

> returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition.

So, if you run the above query and add this code to SELECT, you will get:

```
Timestamp           Value   Timestamp           Value   rn
2017-11-01 19:00    0       NULL                NULL    1
2017-11-01 10:00    0       2017-11-01 13:00    1       1
2017-11-01 11:00    0       2017-11-01 13:00    1       2
2017-11-01 12:00    0       2017-11-01 13:00    1       3
2017-11-01 13:00    1       2017-11-01 15:00    0       1
2017-11-01 14:00    1       2017-11-01 15:00    0       2
2017-11-01 15:00    0       2017-11-01 18:00    1       1
2017-11-01 16:00    0       2017-11-01 18:00    1       2
2017-11-01 17:00    0       2017-11-01 18:00    1       3
2017-11-01 18:00    1       2017-11-01 19:00    0       1
```

As you can see, all rows you need are marked with `1`. We coluld put this in other CTE or sub-query and use `rn = 1` but we can do it all-in-one with the help of `TOP 1 WITH TIES` (MSDN [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql)).

Comment: I'll try this later today, Thanks for you answer. Will let you know how it works

Answer (score 1):

Since you are referring to SQL Server 2012 you can enjoy the new features:

```
;WITH Hist AS (
  SELECT r, 
    LAG(v) OVER(ORDER BY d) PreviousValue,
    v,
    LEAD(v) OVER(ORDER BY d) NextValue ---Just to know that also this is available
  FROM #t
)
SELECT *
FROM Hist h Inner JOIN #t t ON h.r = t.r
WHERE ISNULL(h.PreviousValue, -1) != t.v
```

`#t` contains your results

Answer (score 0):

If this function is a table-valued function, you can just put it in the where or do it inside a function, in this second case as a parameter?

```
Select a.Timestamp, a.Value From [dbo].[nro_ReadRawDataByTimeFunction](
  'SV/SVTP01.BONF0335-D1-W1-BL1',
  '2017-11-01 00:00',
  '2017-12-01 00:00') as a
WHERE a.Value = 1
```

Comment: It's a Table-Valued function yes, but when I try to edit it, it breaks other system that's using this. Note this is not a function that we made, it's from a reporting service.